# Spring Elasticsearch : returning nested document for a query

Tags: spring-data-elasticsearch

I am using Spring Elasticsearch. This is my java class :

```
@Document(indexName = "shopindex")
public class Shop implements Serializable {


  @Field(type = FieldType.Text, name = "name")
  private String name;

  @Field(type = FieldType.Text, name = "address")
  private String address;

  @Field(type = FieldType.Nested, includeInParent = true)
  private ArrayList<Listing> listings;

}
```

This is my Listing class :

```
public class Listing implements Serializable{
   @Field(type = FieldType.Text, name = "ListingName")
   private String name;

   @Field(type = FieldType.Text, name = "ListingDescription")
   private String description;
}
```

I want to search shopindex and return list of Listing objects that contain query string in its name and description field. I have tried this code to search :

```
  NativeSearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
          .withQuery(QueryBuilders.multiMatchQuery(query, "listings"))              
          .build();
  Iterable<Shop> itr = searchRepository.search(searchQuery);
```

I want Listing Iterable instead of Shop Iterable. How do I do that?

Comment: what have you tried so far that is not working?

Comment: I have used search method on ElasticsearchRepository but it returns Iterable of Shop object, I want Iterable of Listing object.

Comment: Updated the question to add what have I tried so far.

Comment: Your domain entity is `Shop` and that's what you have stored in the index. So you get `Shop`s back. You'll have to read the `Listing`s from the `Shop`s and collect them into a list by yourself. By the way, the repository methods taking a query are deprecated since Spring Data Elasticsearch 4.0 and were removed in 4.2

Comment: @P.J.Meisch Is there a way for me to take a Shop object and get list of Listing objects contained in this Shop object that match a query?